# Mail/iCal: How to decline with text / answer mail?

Tags: mail.app, ical, exchange

I am using Mail/iCal with a corporate Exchange server.  With Outlook (yuck!) or its "OWA" approximation, I can answer (accept/maybe/decline) with or without editing the reply mail.  In Mail or iCal, I know three working ways to accept/decline, but I don't see how to edit the reply.  (Plus, after declining, the mail/event is gone, so I also cannot reply to the mail anymore.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on iOS devices, version 8.1.3, this is now directly possible when tapping "decline" using the provided comment field.

Comment: Yes, the situation has improved in iOS 8. I wrote the question when I was still using iOS 7.